# Which gravitational differences we would feel if the sun disappeared?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, earth, sun

I would like to start by stating that I'm not a physicist, I'm purely a curious individual.

I've been speculating about the differences the loss of the sun's gravitational field would have on us and Earth.

Here are my assumptions and speculations.

Assumptions:

1. I'm assuming we would all feel very slightly heavier since we are now being pulled mainly by the gravity of Earth.

Speculations:

1. Earth would no longer have a major opposing force to its own gravity, which would pull all the matter in and around Earth towards the center at a greater pace.
2. Due to Earth's matter being pulled in at a greater pace, the
   increased friction would cause the inner layers of Earth to heat up,
   which would cause volcanic eruptions, earthquakes, and an increased
   core size, all while the outer layer of the planet is freezing.

Any and all interesting facts, feedback, and speculations are welcome.

Comment: "I'm assuming we would all feel very slightly heavier since we are now being pulled mainly by the gravity of Earth"  ... Do you feel noticeably heavier at night?

Comment: @WillO No, good point.

Comment: You wont feel heavier at night because of the tidal force. That is, during the day you are pulled slightly towards the sun and at night the centrifugal force of the orbiting Earth will pull you away from the sun. The heaviest you will feel will be around sunset and sunrise. But all these effects are around 1 part in a million so you'll never notice it anyway. And of course I am ignoring the moon which will still be orbiting us (and us orbiting it!) which also will affect your weight a tiny bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Earth is in orbit around the Sun. For a small body this would feel the same as being in free-fall (according to the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle)) and the Sun's gravity would not affect an object's weight. However, the Earth is large enough that the gravitational acceleration is slightly, but measurably, larger on the side closer to the sun. Therefore, the planet experiences tidal forces due to the Sun. In your hypothetical scenario, these forces would disappear. Earth would be left with the (larger) lunar tides.

The planets are too far away from one another and moving too quickly to be gravitationally bound without the Sun (Earth moves at $\approx 30$ km.s$^{-1}$). Therefore, in the hypothetical scenario, the solar system would fly apart. Nevertheless, the planets would not be able to escape the galaxy (escape velocity $\approx 500$ km.s$^{-1}$). Therefore, the planets would begin to orbit the center of the galaxy individually, rather than collectively as they currently do.

Comment: Would the loss of the sun have any effect on the internals(behavior, temperature, etc.) or Earth or the frequency of natural disasters such as volcanic eruptions?
Also, thanks for the reply, it really helped me understand the concept a lot better.

Comment: The immediate effect probably wouldn’t be dramatic. Tidal forces due to the sun already reverse direction with respect to the Earth every 12 hours. Removing them completely wouldn’t suddenly cause unusually large seismic stresses. However, removing these tidal forces would reduce the amplitude of the Earth tide, and this phenomenon could have a role in triggering seismic activity.